# Using enum mapped property value in another enum map in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I'm trying to build Flutter Custom themes and I use enum to define the properties. I'm trying to group common theme properties and use them in my custom themes (both enum maps) but I could not get it to work.

```
  enum AppCommonTheme {
    AppDark,
    AppLight,
  }

  final appCommonTheme = {
    AppCommonTheme.AppDark: ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
    ),
    AppCommonTheme.AppLight: ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
    ),    
  }

  enum AppTheme {
    GreenLight,
    GreenDark,
    BlueLight,
    BlueDark,
  }

  final appThemeData = {
    AppTheme.GreenLight: ThemeData(
      brightness: AppCommonTheme.AppLight[brightness],
      primaryColor: Colors.green,
      accentColor: Colors.green[100],
    ),
    AppTheme.GreenDark: ThemeData(
      brightness: AppCommonTheme.AppDark[brightness],
      primaryColor: Colors.green,
      accentColor: Colors.green[50],
    ),
  };
```

In the above code, I'm trying to derive `brighness` in `AppTheme.GreenLight` from `brightness` in `AppCommonTheme.AppLight`. The above code `brightness: AppCommonTheme.AppLight[brightness]` or all its variations I tried did not work.

Is this possible?  Or is there a better way to do such inheritance?

I feel I could use `extension methods` for this but have no idea how to do this with enums. All the examples that I see deal with simple enum scenarios with no complex maps so I'm kinda lost here.

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's " appCommonTheme[AppCommonTheme.AppLight].brightness " since AppCommonTheme.AppLight is just a key inside the appCommonTheme map and not the ThemeData object itself.

For "a better way to do it", you could try using .copyWith() from the base theme:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final baseThemeDark = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.dark,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
);

final baseThemeLight = ThemeData(
  brightness: Brightness.light,
  scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xFFEFEFEF),
);

final greenThemeDark = baseThemeDark.copyWith(
  primaryColor: Colors.green,
  accentColor: Colors.green[100],
);

// etc
```